# Find statistical sweet spots for number of product images

Tags: python, math, statistics

I work for a company that rents out privately owned objects. When I did a random scatter plot of the number of bookings of an object in relation to the number of images of the object, there seemed to be some kind of correlation indicated.

I got a high number of bookings for objects around the 5 - 7 picture mark.
What is the best statistical way to define a "sweet spot" for the amount of pictures that any boat should have?

This would for example be useful for our FAQs.
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: If you're referring to a website, oftentimes, users that submit very little information about a listing, don't believe the listing is very good, thus at least partially explaining the performance between images and sell through of the boat. If you really wanted to say that images drive the sale, you would want to disprove my theory (either through manual inspection and saying "this boat is good, the photos are bad"). Typically, in the real world, at least for your FAQ/help center articles, you would simply say that listings with at least 7 images have a x% higher chance of selling. My 2 cents

Comment: Yeah I do realize that images are definitely not the only driving factor. I just thought it would be really interesting if I can find a correlation at all. It is not necessarily going to be used on the website.